# Jquery DatePicker does not load color or any style info

Tags: jquery

I have a web form in which I've added the JQuery date picker. When developing in Visual Studio and testing the forms in the browser, the date picker loads as expected. When I push the forms to the production environment, the form loads the picker but has no styling, displaying the calendar as text links. How might I go about determining what could be different between the 2 environments?

The production environment is a windows 2019 server PC running IIS and .net 4.8

My Dev PC is a windows 10 PC running Visual Studio 2012.

Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#VIRTUSDate").datepicker();
});

$(function () {
    $("#BGdate").datepicker();
});

$(function () {
    $("#COCDate").datepicker();
});
</script>

<input type="text" name="VIRTUSDate" id="VIRTUSDate" value="<%= Session("VIRTUSDate")%>" onchange="checkboxx(this.form)" style="width:87px" />

<input type="text" name="BGdate" id="BGdate" value="<%= Session("bgdate")%>" onchange="checkboxx(this.form)" style="width:87px"/>

<input type="text" name="COCDate" id="COCDate" value="<%= Session("COCDate")%>" onchange="checkboxx(this.form)" style="width:87px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out my issue. The developer tools in the browser told me the jquery-ui.css was not loading because loading of mixed content was being blocked. Somehow, I managed to type http:// instead of https://.